# Jasper report +ZK exception?

Tags: jasper-reports, zk

I am using JasperReport(jasperreports-4.5.0.jar) with Zk Framework(6.0.2) and when i am trying to display Jasper report in Model Window i am getting below exception.

> > HTTP Status 410 - Failed to load /view/z_ghu/t_257/bbi/0/core/report/Report.pdf Cause:
> >     net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from
> >     InputStream
>
> type Status report
>
> message Failed to load
>   /view/z_ghu/t_257/bbi/0/core/report/Report.pdf Cause:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from
>   InputStream   description The requested resource (Failed to load
>   /view/z_ghu/t_257/bbi/0/core/report/Report.pdf Cause:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from
>   InputStream ) is no longer available, and no forwarding address is
>   known.
>
> Apache Tomcat/6.0.35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue in my Build path i am using the

> itext-2.1.4.jar

That was the cause of above exception i updated with

> itext-2.1.7.jar

and my code worked fine.I added a sample code with exception [Here](http://zkframeworkhint.blogspot.in/2012/10/integrate-zk-with-jasper-report.html)